# HTML/Javascript anchor to another section not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Apologies if this has been answered but I cannot find something specific to my issue. I am trying to do a simple 'scroll down' link to a different section of the page like so:

```
<a href="#apply-profile">scroll down</a>
```

This would then link to a form at the bottom of the page defined as:

```
<form class="recipe" method="post" id="apply-profile”>
```

This works just fine on Chrome. This however does not work on Firefox for example. I am not sure what the issue is. I am open to a Javascript solution if need be, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the fancy quote in your real HTML? `id="apply-profile”>`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `id="apply-profile”` to `id="apply-profile"` (notice the closing quotation marks).

Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This did not do it for me unfortunately.

Comment: Please can you post your HTML? Perhaps there is something causing the issue that was not mentioned in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

try putting empty link into your form like this:

```
<a id="apply-profile"></a>
```

haven't tested that, but I saw some people do it like this

Comment: <a href="javascript:myFunction()">scroll down</a> //This is essentially what I think the solution would look like